# Button Counter text animate top to down

Tags: android

I am building a simple counter app. I have a `button` which starts countdown on pressing, also the countdown text will appear on the same button too. i want countdown text on button animate like top to down when it change to new number.
I know there is solution with a `textview` but i cant find any button's text.
P.S i used `CountDownTimer` class to countdown,Here is the code.

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")

CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(15000,1000);

//some codes--
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
            timer.start();
  }
    };
 }

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

        public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

             millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            System.out.println(hms);

            play.setText(hms);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: have you had a look at the side bar? With the information you provide, I think they could help you.

Answer (score 0):

An Android `Button`, is actually a `TextView`, so see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389011/819355

**UPDATE:**

Based on comments, here's a possible solution using `CountDownTimer` and `TextSwitcher` (note: not tested):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="Click me" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class MyClass {

    TextSwitcher textSwitcher;

    ...
    CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(15000,1000);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });

    textSwitcher = new TextSwitcher(context);
    textSwitcher.setInAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_left); // use any animation
    textSwitcher.setOutAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    textSwitcher.addView(findViewById(R.id.text1));
    textSwitcher.addView(findViewById(R.id.text2));
    ...

    public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

            public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                ...
                textSwitcher.setText(hms); // will now animate text
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: i used CountDownTimer class to countdown. is this work?

Comment: added codes in question. Please have a look. Thanks. i still have no idea why someone voted negative. i cant find any solution for this.

Comment: the down-vote is probably because you haven't posted any code or mentioned what you've tried so far. based on your code, I would follow @Ankit answer and use a TextSwitcher that wraps *2* buttons. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7574268/819355 (change the TextView with a Button)

Comment: i have only one button and this works only when sliding through buttons i want change animation of text within a button.

Comment: you can't move text around without some view containing it. you can create a button, and on top of it two text views (use either RelativeLayout or FrameLayout to position the three views), hide the textviews while counter is inactive, and animate via TextSwitcher when counter starts